# remove a row and sort a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting

I want to transform `df1` to `df2`

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(v=c('xxx', 1, 10, 5), f=c(4, 3, 2, 7))
# df1 =
   v f
1  ? 4
2  1 7
3 10 2
4  5 7
```

I want to remove the first row where `v` = `'xxx'`. Then sort the dataframe by the values of column `v` in ascending order. The final result should be like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(v=c(1, 5, 10), f=c(3, 7, 2))
# df2 =
   v f
1  1 3
2  5 7
3 10 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the row where the value is `'xxx'`, use `type.convert` to convert into it's appropriate class and then `order` the data.

```
df2 <- type.convert(subset(df1, v != 'xxx'))
df2[order(df2$v), ]

#   v f
#2  1 3
#4  5 7
#3 10 2
```

---

Using `dplyr` we can do the same using `filter` and `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% filter(v != 'xxx') %>% type.convert() %>% arrange(v)
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(v=c('xxx', 1, 10, 5), f=c(4, 3, 2, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which works by subtracting from the dataframe that row `which` matches the pattern `xxx`:

```
df2 <- df1[-which(grepl("xxx", apply(df1, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
```

Alternatively, simple subsetting works too:

```
df2 <- df1[df1$v != "xxx",]
```

or:

```
df2 <- df1[!df1$v == "xxx",]
```

Then you only have to convert the data in the dataframe to numeric:

```
df2[] <- lapply(df2[], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Now you can order it:

```
df2 <- df2[order(df2$v),]
df2
   v f
2  1 3
4  5 7
3 10 2
```